# Простая анимация при изменение содержимого блока (CSS)?

Tags: html, css, css-animation

Имеется `.wrapper` состоящий из `.item`, по событию будут удаляться, либо добавляться новые `.item`. Высота и ширина `.wrapper` изначально не известна.

Как реализовать следующую анимацию:

1. При изменение количества `.item`, размер `.wrapper` должен плавно увеличиваться.
2. Спустя 0.5s после увеличения `.wrapper`, должны плавно появиться `.item`.

Хочу наглядно понять, как правильно писать подобного рода анимации.

```css
.wrapper
{
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">item1</div>
  <div class="item">item2</div>
  <div class="item">item3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Дмытрык это без разницы, даже если у него фона не будет, он все равно будет воздействовать на блоки ниже (плавно их выталкивать).

Comment: Это на собеседованиях такие задания?

Comment: `.item` фиксированной высоты?

Comment: @Дмытрык возможно, но я не вкурсе... :)

Comment: @Heidel нет, там будет любое содержимое, следовательно габариты его не известны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("elem");
var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
wrapper.addEventListener("transitionend", setOpacity);
btn.addEventListener("click", go);

function  go(event){
var valueChild = 5;
var height = valueChild * 200;
wrapper.style.height = height +"px";
for (var i=0; i<valueChild; i++){
 var div = document.createElement("div");
 div.className = "item";
 div.innerText = "item"+i;
 wrapper.appendChild(div);
}
}

function setOpacity() {
setTimeout(function(){
var child = wrapper.children;
for (var i=0; i<child.length; i++){
 child[i].style.opacity = "1";
}
},500)
}t
```

```css
#wrapper{
width: 200px;
background: blue;
height: 0px;
transition: 4s;
overflow: hidden;
}
.item{
color: yellow;
border: 1px solid;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
opacity: 0;
transition: 3s;
}
```

```html
<button id="elem">Клик</button> 

<div id="wrapper" class="wrapper"></div>
```